# Xamarin Forms Picker like iOS Picker

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker

I'm trying to figure out how to create a picker that looks like the iOS Picker but works across Android and UWP.

I want to bind it to a list of strings and have a slot-machine type view of them.

[image]

Something similar to the Syncfusion Date/Time Picker.

[image]

I tried the new CarouselView in Xamarin Forms v4.4 but it wants to use the whole page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use the Syncfusion's DateTime picker? If that is the UI you desire?

Comment: Is DateTime is not what you are looking for then, Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPicker has the same UI. Check it out.

Comment: I don't understand CarouselView wants to use the whole page.